# Xamarin Java Library Binding

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin.android

I'm trying to create a Java Binding Library for Xamarin.Android.

I have created library with several errors, but i have handled them.

Problem exists when I'm trying to use this library in Xamarin.Android project.

I'm trying to port FreeFLow library

This is my application build result (posted only one of ~30 similar errors):

`Error  1    package com.comcast.freeflow.core.AbsLayoutContainer does not exist
        com.comcast.freeflow.core.AbsLayoutContainer.OnItemClickListener`

And this error leads to .java file, which starts with:

```
public class AbsLayoutContainer_OnItemClickListenerImplementor
    extends java.lang.Object
    implements
        mono.android.IGCUserPeer,
        com.comcast.freeflow.core.AbsLayoutContainer.OnItemClickListener
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find solution?

Comment: Ran into this as well. Binding library builds fine. Consumer project fails.